# What is proc/ directory in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, proc

I am navigating one of my Ubuntu servers and was wondering what the numbers *1-26758* are under the *proc/* folder. Are these ports or something else?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> proc - process information pseudo-filesystem

The [proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manual page says:

```
   The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an
   interface to kernel data structures.  It is commonly mounted at
   /proc.  Typically, it is mounted automatically by the system, but it
   can also be mounted manually using a command such as:

       mount -t proc proc /proc

   Most of the files in the proc filesystem are read-only, but some
   files are writable, allowing kernel variables to be changed.
```

And the directories  *1-26758* they are nothing but processes represented by `PID`.The files inside the numbered directory corresponds to the process with that particular PID. This directory will contain files like  *limits,mounts,etc.* which will gives information about the process.